# To achieve local media tracks when deploying ionic application in IOS using twilio

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, safari, uiwebview, twilio-video

I am building an ionic application. I am using twilio-video sdk to implement video call. I am able to work it in android devices and browser. When i try to deploy it on IOS, the mobile UI Webview browser does not let me use the getUserMedia() function.

Error: getUserMedia() is not supported

Apple developer forums states that it supports only safari 11 and not any other Webkit Views. Has anyone came to a solution?

Also is there a way to get local media tracks when building an ionic application in ios?